# Moodle Can't Import PNG larger than 100K

Tags: graphics, png, moodle

This is a strange problem. If I used `moodle.sty from https://gitlab.mattgk.myds.me/mattguer/moodle/` and `includegraphics` for my PNG pictures, anything larger than 100K will not be imported. This for the Rebel theme.

However, I can use their question builder on Moolde Site I have no problem with pictures bigger than 100K.

Upon looking at the XML files, I found the difference:

One generated by the moodle.sty looks like this

```
<text> 
      <![CDATA] QUESTION TEXT HERE <IMG width=555 SRC="data:image/png;base64, IMAGINE CODEs HERE">>
<\text>
```

The one generated by the moodle question builder looks like this.

```
<text> 
     <![CDATA] QUESTION TEXT HERE <img src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/F.PNG" alt="triangle" width="330" height="550" class="img-responsive atto_image_button_middle">>
<\text>

<file name="F.PNG" path="/" encoding="base64"> IMAGE CODEs HERE </file>}
```

THE KEY DIFFERENCE IS THE ONE THE QUESTION BUILDER USED A SEPARATE FILE PATH FOR THE IMAGE.

I'm trying to modify the moodle.sty code by replacing

```
\edef\htmlize@imagetag{<IMG SRC="data:\TikzExportMIME;base64,\csname picbaselxiv@\the\numpicturesread\endcsname">}%
```

by

```
\edef\htmlize@imagetag{<img src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/#2" alt="triangle" width="\moodle@graphics@width@pixels" height="\moodle@graphics@height@pixels" class="img-responsive atto_image_button_middle">
\writetomoodle{<file name="#2" path="/" encoding="base64"> \csname picbaselxiv@graphics@#2\endcsname </file>}%
```

But it does't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm... have you checked if the encoded image is generated correctly? I remember I had a problem with ImageMagick limits on conversions...

Comment: @Kevin L when you say "import", you talk about the XML import process of the Moodle LMS, right? If so, what is the import error? Is the problem reproducible with the [Moodle demo sites](https://moodle.org/demo)? Also, could you please tell us if the problem encountered is specific to the development version of `moodle` or if it can be reproduced with version 0.5 (currently on CTAN).

Comment: @mgk The error message is  "error writing to database more information about this error". I'm using Moodle 3.10. This problem won't happen if I use the moodlecloud site but with the localhost, it won't import PNG bigger than 100K. Maybe it is some setting I need to tune but I can't figure what. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Rmano Yes. The images are correct. It doesn't have to do with the image conversion. It has to do with how moodle, or more specifically, how the Rebel Theme, may limit the image size. 100K is not a random number. It must be specified somewhere. But I can't track down where the specification here. The only way I can think of to work around it is by modifying the format of the XML. But doing it one by one by hand is impossible. It would be great if you can point out how to modify the STYLE file to output the XML in the right format. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy of the `moodle` LaTeX package is to embed images directly in the question text, rather than in separate files (with `<file>` tag in XML). This could evolve but, at the moment, the philosophy is to avoid relying upon Moodle's file management system (see first section of documentation). As a consequence, the question fields can become quite large when it includes large images.

Apparently, in some kind of way, Moodle's [Rebel theme](https://moodle.org/plugins/theme_rebel) limits the size of question fields when importing a XML question bank (I lack information to say more on the matter). I am not even convinced that the `<file>` way of including images will pass the import process.

I have no perfect solution for your problem but here are some working directions that I can think of:

1. See with the Rebel theme authors in order to identify the origin of the 100 KB limitation and how it could be overridden.
2. Change theme.
3. Install [`optipng`](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) and make sure it is used by `moodle` in order to have the graphics optimized and, hopefully, your graphics will be less than 100 KB.
4. Manually adapt the XML file for the syntax using the `<file>` tag.
5. Open an [issue](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/issues) to ask for a future version of `moodle` to include an option triggering the `<file>` way of including images. As your attempt has shown, this is non-trivial.